# Inserting Multiple Rows into Table based on Number of Rows in Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to insert rows into the Attendance_Check Table based on the number of Students in the related class. For every student in the class, they should have a row in the attendance_check table.

Relevant Tables include: Attendance_Record, Att_Check, Student, and Class

```
declare @i int;

/* 1. Create a new Record for specified class and date*/

INSERT INTO Attendance_Record (Class_ID, Att_Date)
VALUES('1', GETDATE()); /* insert class_ID for the class the teacher is recording attendance for)*/

SELECT @i= SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Att_Check (Att_ID, Stu_ID)
VALUES((SELECT @i), (SELECT S.Stu_ID
        FROM Student S
            INNER JOIN Class C
                ON S.Class_ID=C.Class_ID
        WHERE C.Class_ID='1'))
```

This code is attempting to populate the attendance_check tables with both the attendance id that correlates to class 1 and the students belonging to class 1.

At the current time, this only gives me an error that the Subquery returned more than one value. I do understand why that is, but I am having trouble thinking about how to rewrite the code to get around it. I'd like the results to end up like so:

```
Attendance Record Table
Att_ID | Class_ID | Date
1          1         10/10/2019


Attendance Check Table
Att_ID| Stu_ID | Stu_Status
1        1
1        2   
1        3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting from a query with a `VALUES` clause isn't advisable in most case. Use and `INSERT ... SELECT` instead.

```
INSERT INTO att_check
           (att_id,
            stu_id)
           SELECT @i,
                  s.stu_id
           FROM student s
                INNER JOIN class c
                           ON s.class_id = c.class_id
           WHERE c.class_id = 1;
```

There's also no need to enclose numeric literals in single quotes.